# добавление даты как index

Tags: r

Здравствуйте.

Прошу подсказать каким образом можно добавить дату как index в df.
При скачивании котировок дата уже добавлена как index, требуется то же самое сделать для df добавленной посредством read.csv

Вот пример того:

```
library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("^GSPC",src="yahoo",from=as.Date("2017-07-01",to=Sys.Date()))
[1] "GSPC"
> df<-read.csv("D:\\R\\tmp1\\SiM7.csv",header=F,skip=1,sep=";")
```

(как должно быть)

```
> GSPC[1,]
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2017-07-03   2431.39   2439.17  2428.69    2429.01  1962290000       2429.01
>
```

(как получается)

```
> df[1,]
    V1 V2       V3     V4    V5    V6    V7    V8     V9 V10
1 SiM7  5 20170522 100000 57236 57236 56767 56785 108295   0
>
```

добавить посредством index(df)<-df[,3] не получается, дату нужно добавить уже имеющуюся и импортируемую посредством read.csv
Прошу помощи, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос удалось решить-)

```
> library(quantmod)
> df1<-paste(df[,3],df[,4]) #объединение в одну колонку
> df_date_vec<-strptime(df1, "%Y%m%d %H%M%S") #выделение даты и времени
> df2 <- xts(df, order.by = df_date_vec) #склейка даты и времени с данными
> df2<-df2[,5:8]
```

желаемый результат достигнут:

```
> df2[1,]
                   V5    V6    V7    V8
2017-05-22 10:00:00 57236 57236 56767 56785
```